# How can I push multiple messages to a topic in a single asynchronous call

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, kafka-topic

I am using Google Cloud Platform. I need to push messages from different source to a topic, but it should be done using a single asynchronous call.

Answer (score 1):

Batching Cloud Pub/Sub messages can be done and implemented using the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries). Have a look at the official GCP documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publisher-batch-settings-python) for examples in different programming languages.

Comment: ^^ This is correct. In fact, they have default batch settings. Note that most client libraries will start the batching in the background when you create your pubsub object and you will post things individually in your code.